# Drupal Flag module - View of flagged users containing duplicates

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've got a Flag setup within Drupal that enables a user to flag node authors, with the purpose of creating a list of favourite users.

I have added `<?php print flag_create_link('favourite_user', $node->uid); ?>` to the relevant node template, and have set up a page View to show the list of flagged users.

Things are mostly working, except I'm getting duplicate entries. It shows each user n times, where n is the number of nodes they have created. Selecting 'Distinct - Yes' in the View doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a 'node' view rather than a 'user' view... :)